# Font quality/scaling (DPI) in wxStyledTextCtrl / wxwidgets

Tags: fonts, wxwidgets, dpi, wxstyledtextctrl

Have wxWidgets-3.0.5.

Most of interface has correct DPI scaling, but wxStyledTextCtrl not

Even if set big size and make zoom.

Does anyone know solution?

[image: Bad font scaling]

Comment: what wx version? What platform?

Comment: wx 3.0.5, windows platform.

looks like wxWidgets-3.0.5 uses scintilla 3.2.1

but according to their changelog high DPI came only from 3.6.0

Comment: can you try with 3.1.5? Are you using Manifest with DPI-Aware set?

Comment: also, can you try with `stcdemo`? And if you have access to plain Scintilla can compile it - test it and let us know.

Comment: compiled scite, both 3.2.1 and 3.6.0 have perfect DPI scaling;

compiled wxWidgest-3.1.5 https://pastebin.com/YbZ2TH8Y; 

used this manifest https://pastebin.com/4j4q68xy;

wxStyledTextCtrl has bad DPI scaling

Comment: As said above, DPI awareness wasn't added to wxSTC until fairly recently,  I think it was in 3.1.4 but it may have been 3.1.5 which was only released a few weeks ago.

Comment: As I said above, compiled wxWidgest-3.1.5, DPI awareness is not working for wxSTC, you can compile yourself and check https://pastebin.com/YbZ2TH8Y

Comment: here is the screenshot
https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/3299139/117005878-94576b00-ad09-11eb-96ea-3aae3c33204e.png

Comment: @Falseclock, can you try to compile `stcdemo` sample and not some arbitrary code?